# Open VS Code project inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code

I want to open directory in vscode through shell script. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODE=`which code`
PATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/myusername
if [ ${CODE}=="/usr/bin/code" ]; then
    ${CODE} ${PATH}$1;
fi
```

When executed:

> $ bash myscript.sh projectname
>
> /usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory

What give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like vscode doesn't support it yet.

Please refer to this issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13138